# Get Parent Node using Jayway JSONPATH

Tags: java, jsonpath, jayway

In the below JSON file I want to extract the `empDetails.name` where one or both `iscomponentInSal` is true .

JSON

```
[
*// Retrieve below `empDetails.name` as for one of the components we have `"iscomponentInSal": true`* 
  {
    "empDetails": {
    "name":"John",
      "compensation": {
        "salary": [
          {
            "component": "Basic",
            "iscomponentInSal": true
          },
          {
            "component": "HRA",
            "iscomponentInSal": false
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
*// Do not retrieve below `empDetails.name` as for both components we have `"iscomponentInSal": false`* 
{
    "empDetails": {
    "name":"Steve",
      "compensation": {
        "salary": [
          {
            "component": "Basic",
            "iscomponentInSal": false
          },
          {
            "component": "HRA",
            "iscomponentInSal": false
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I tried few ways to extract the results as below , but was not successfull

`$.[salary[?(@.iscomponentInSal  == true)])]`

//This retrieves below json

```
[
  {
    "component": "Basic",
    "iscomponentInSal": true
  }
]
```

Comment: _I tried few ways to extract the results but was not successfull_ You should include what you tried

Comment: Just curious to know how you determine if the salary is paid or not when you have both values for `isSalaryPaid` in the array.

Comment: @AkshayG updated the nodes for your understanding . Problem statement is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different possible solutions using [Jayway-JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) Filter Operators

using nested expressions and **empty** filter operator.

```
$[*].empDetails[?(@.compensation.salary[?(@.iscomponentInSal == true)] empty false)].name
```

using **in** filter operator; right side expression returns an array

```
$[*].empDetails[?(true in @.compensation.salary[*].iscomponentInSal)].name
```